# Validation in method continues to run the rest of code even though "return" is specified

Tags: c#, .net, methods, return

My code doesn't terminate on a true condition if called from another method. For example,

```
void RunValidation()
{
    if (NameEntered == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No name has been entered");
        return;
    }
}

void CreateUser()
{
    RunValidation();

    //Run more code
}
```

If I call the validation method inside the create user method, the messagebox shows up but the rest of the code gets executed even though "return" was specified.

If the validation code is not inside a method and called directly in the CreateUser method, the rest of the code doesn't run (which is what I want). I want to be able to call a validation method inside many other methods and if the conditions are true, to stop executing other code in the methods.

What is the correct way of doing this? Do I have to use some sort of try and catch?

Comment: You have not closed the RunValidation() function properly.

Comment: @arunlalam looks closed to me

Comment: My bad. I thought I saw a quote missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from the `RunValidation` method, not the `CreateUser` method.  If you want to control the flow of the `CreateUser` method based on the results of `RunValidation`, do something like this:

```
bool Validate()
{
    if (NameEntered.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No name has been entered");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void CreateUser()
{
    if (Validate())
    {
        // Run more code
    }
}
```

The `return` statement only affects the current method.  Read more about the `return` statement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx).

Comment: This somewhat works. I would then have to check if Validate() == true. Then the code functions properly. But using this method means adding more lines of code and an extra if else statement.

Comment: `Validate()` evaluates to a `bool`, so you don't need to check `Validate() == true` unless you want it for readability purposes.  This isn't an "extra if else statement" - it's a *necessary* if-else statement.  `return` functions within the method in which it's called *only*.

Comment: To prevent indented code in the `if` block, you can just use:
`if (!Validate()) return;
// Run more code`

Answer (score 2):

`return;` exits the `RunValidation()` method.
It has no effect on the function that called it.

Instead, you should make `RunValidation()` return a boolean indicating whether the validation succeeded.
In the calling method, you can check if it returns `false` and `return;` from there too.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
bool RunValidation()
{
    if (NameEntered == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No name has been entered");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void CreateUser()
{
    if(RunValidation())
    {

        //Run more code
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U talking about this code block?

```
void RunValidation()
{
    if (NameEntered == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No name has been entered");
        return;
    }
}
```

because if you are, I don't know what "rest of code" it's executing, because there is no code after the return statement.

If you're talking about this

```
void CreateUser()
{
    RunValidation();

    //Run more code
}
```

then yes, just because `RunValidation` had a return statement doesn't mean that it's calling method will return.  that kind of behavior would cause crazy bugs.

---

Now, in order to achieve yoru expected behavior, you can change `runValidation` to

```
bool RunValidation()
{
    if (NameEntered == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No name has been entered");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and then call it like

```
void CreateUser()
{
    if(RunValidation())
    {

        //Run more code
    }
}
```